# Obtener URL amigable con PHP

Tags: php, php7, php5

estoy intentando obtener la url amigable vía PHP, no estoy intentando configurar .htaccess.

Quiero recoger la url procesada para ponerla en un  pero $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] me devuelve la dirección original.

Hay alguna manera de obtenerlo con php?

Comment: has probado con algo? existe algun codigo el cual podriamos ver para poder ayudarte?

Comment: SI ( isset ( $_SERVER ['HTTPS'] ) ? 'https://' : 'http://' ) . $_SERVER ['SERVER_NAME'] . '/' . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], esto me devuelve la URI original, pero no la URI amigable que configuré en .htaccess

Comment: A lo que me refiero, yo en mis enlaces tengo https://www.example.com/post/asG38sdGFg9344sdf93 y es lo que quiero obtener con PHP, en cambio obtengo https://www.example.com/post.php?id=asG38sdGFg9344sdf93

Comment: @El Tito Barte edita la pregunta y añade el código y los datos que comentas. Se entenderá mejor. Porn el .htaccess también. Sino es muy dificil ayudarte.

Comment: Pero... realmente estás accediendo con la URL amigable?